# Why can't I import package in the same module?

Tags: go, module, package

I have some problem with Golang about importing local only package. This is my project structure

```
home/src/github.com/username/project1
|main.go
|go.mod
├── handlers
│   ├── handlers.go
├── usecases
|   ├─ ...
|...
```

my `go.mod`

```
module project1

go 1.16
```

my `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    
    "project1/handlers/handlers"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", handlers.Greet)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

my `handlers/handlers.go`

```
package handlers

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func Greet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

I'm building this outside the GOPATH which is `C:\users\...\go` and I am using go 1.16.

After reading some sources that said I can just use the module name and path to the package to import the package I use this line to import `handlers` package to `main` package.

```
import "project1/handlers/handlers"
```

But this returns this error when I tried to run it.

```
package project1/handlers/handlers is not in GOROOT (C:\...\project1/handlers/handlers)
```

Then I tried to change some stuff like changing both my module name and import path to this

```
//module name in go.mod
module github.com/username/project1

//import path in main.go
import "github.com/username/project1/handlers/handlers"
```

but then it returns error that said I need to get the package first with `go get github.com/username/project1/handlers/handlers` which when I tried to get it with that command or just simply `go mod tidy` returns `repository not found` error because I haven't push/publish this project and I'm not planning to do it.

So, what is the problem/mistake that I made here? do I have to publish my project before I can import my own local package? Did I miss some configuration? Every single help is appreciated.

Comment: Try building in the directory where `go.mod` exists.

Comment: Use `import "project1/handlers"`. Packages correspond to directories.

Comment: @CeriseLimón ah.. it works, thanks! then, do I need to name my directories like my packages? Also, it means that I can't have more than 1 package in 1 directory right?

Comment: Don't put answers in your question. Instead, click the answer button at the bottom. I've already moved your answer to a proper answer, but if you want to do it yourself to earn any reputation, I'll delete mine.

Comment: "do I need to name my directories like my packages? Also, it means that I can't have more than 1 package in 1 directory right" yes, yes. This is all explained in detail on golang.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put too many path in the import path, it should stop at the directory rather than package. So by changing the import path to

```
import "project1/handlers"

//rather than
import "project1/handlers/handlers"
```

fixed the problem. Thanks!